# A topological question of division

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a relation between $K(\Bbb Z[\frac{1}2],1)$,$K(\Bbb Z,1)$? Why is $K(\Bbb Z[\frac{1}2],1)$ like $K(\Bbb Z,1)$ 'divided' by 2?

Comment: What do you mean by the latter statement? Since $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is not finitely-generated (as an abelian group), $K(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}], 1)$ is not even a finite complex.

Comment: 15:58 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUuECLebqtU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ away from $2$. Similarly, there is a notion of [localization of spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_topological_space), and $B \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is the localization of $B \mathbb{Z}$ away from $2$.